# ElasticSearch - Full Text Search on nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

If someone can help?
    1. The full text search  query where title and description are both top level fields

```
GET /docidx/Document/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "title:computer AND description:electronics"
        }
     }
}

This works fine.

2. The full text search query where title is top level field but "abstract.content" i.e content is a nested field under abstract - does not return results.

GET /docidx/Document/_search
{
  "query": {
       "query_string": {
          "query": "title:computer AND abstract.content:memory"
        }
    }
}

Does Elastic Search has support for full text search for nested fields?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of `must` and `nested Query`:

```
GET /docidx/Document/_search
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
              "default_field": "title",
              "query": "computer"
           }
        },
        {
           "nested": {
              "path": "abstract",
              "query": {
                 "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "abstract.content",
                    "query": "memory"
                 }
              }
           }
          }
       ]
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: But How to parse this phrase "title:computer AND abstract.content:memory". OR there might be some complex phrase like :-    "((title:computer AND description:electronics OR (serialNum:123 AND misc:test)) OR server"

Comment: You can not club nested and non-nested fields in same query_string. Club all nested fields within one query and non-nested in other and apply `must` or `should` between both as per the requirement